# Get slug of current category in functions.php

Tags: functions, categories

I want to use a certain archive template for a bunch of different parent categories. Therefor I try to change the archive template by using the `'archive_template'` filter in functions.php by identifying what slug the current category has.

I've tried to retrieve the category slug by using three different methods as you can see below, but none of them seem to work. What's the correct way of retrieving the current category in functions.php?

```
function use_custom_template($tpl){
    global $post;

    $tryOne = get_the_category( $post->ID );    
    $tryTwo = get_the_category();
    $tryThree = get_queried_object();
      
  if (is_tax("sport-fritid-parent") {
    $tpl = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/category-custom-parent.php';
  }
  return $tpl;
}

add_filter( 'archive_template', 'use_custom_template' ) ;
```

Comment: you can't do this by retrieving the current post, because there is no current post yet, the template and the post loop haven't happened yet, if you're trying to show a specific template for a specific archive of a specific category, why not use the built in template heirarchy support? You can always `require` or `get_template_part` in that file if you need to share the code across multiple files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_queried_object` is how you retrieve the term for the current category, although you have to be careful to check for this, as it may not be a category archive. It could be a date archive, or a tag archive, etc etc

At a minimum you should include an `is_category` check:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/

Reading the docs for `is_category` also reveals it takes a parameter so not only can you check if it's a category, you can use it to check if it's a specific category.

You should also look into using `locate_template` to grab the path to the file rather than `dirname( __FILE__ )`. This is because the current code has no support for child themes or plugin overrides.

see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/

Another solution would have been to use `category-sport-fritid-parent.php` and then inside that file called `get_template_part` to pull in a shared template file.

For reference, here is the official documentation for the filter you're trying to use:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/

And post in the comments of that doc is an example doing exactly what you're asking how to do:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/#comment-4683

Comment: But the $tryThree->slug returns nothing. Perhaps it's easier for me to check this in the actual category.php template with a simple if statement, instead of using two separate category templates?

Comment: Did you try the other 2 suggestions I made? Did `is_category` not work? Are you sure this is a category archive and not a page template or page builder screen that implements a category archive? And that the slug is exactly `sport-fritid-parent`? And is this the category taxonomy that comes with WordPress or a custom taxonomy that's been added by yourself or a theme/plugin that has the name category?

Comment: I need to retrieve the slug of the currently queried category object, doesn't is_category just simply check if it's a category or not?

Comment: yes but if you read the doc I linked you'd see it also takes arguments that let you check if it's a specific category

Comment: someone posted an example on the official doc for the filter you're using doing exactly that to achieve your goal using a custom taxonomy instead and `is_tax`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/#comment-2720

Comment: and an example for categories https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/#comment-4683

Comment: is_tax works to check if you already know the slug, but I want to get the slug of the current category, namely the category you've navigated to. My question is describing all methods I've tried to receive the slug of the current category from functions.php

Comment: If `is_tax` works then why not use that and write it as an answer? Your question implies that you already know the slugs you want to check for, is that not the case? Note that if `is_tax` works but `is_category` does not, that implies that you are not using a category, but are using a custom taxonomy ( e.g. product categories in woocommerce are a custom taxonomy )

Comment: Also, if `get_queried_object` does not give you what you want, have you checked what it's actually returning? That's _valuable_ information that you should get and edit into your question. Something is missing that we're both assuming the other knows, or that's being labelled as "well it should be X therefore.." that's not being checked and confirmed directly. e.g. it would be useful to know what the value of `$tpl` is before the checks ( `wp_die( var_export( $tpl ) );` ) or what `$tryThree` is ( `wp_die( var_export( get_queried_object() ) )` ).